# Resetting django_sessions

Tags: django, django-models

I was playing around with storing session ids for **anonymous** users in django models using django.contrib.sessions.models and tested all browsers on my machine creating different keys sometimes based on the real and incognito sessions.

I followed it up by deleting my database and creating a new one as part of my tests and development emptying out all tables.

I am noticing now that when I revisit the site from the same computer/browser, django does NOT create and store a new session id even though the table is empty which means that the server is storing the information that I previously visited the site as an anon user somewhere other than the django_sessions table.

I tested clearing out my cookies and history but that did not help. Does anyone know where that information is stored, why, and how can I reset it? This is an issue mainly because I am using the session id as foreignkey and if i do end up deleting the database after deployment for any reason, i dont want the program to not work properly.

Using python 3.8 and django 3.0.2

Thanks.

Comment: Django only creates a session in the database when you try to write to it. Merely visiting your site will not generate a session unless the view you visit actually writes to the session.

Comment: Thank you. that makes sense.